# How can I use regular expressions in Textpad to remove anything, line by line, before specified characters?

Tags: textpad

```
aaaaa1bbbbb
ccccc2ddddd
eeeee3fffff
```

I want to remove all characters before numbers, after replacing file, it should look like

```
bbbbb
ddddd
fffff
```

Comment: `s/^.*([0-9]+.*)/\1/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Find and Replace` dialog box enter these values:

1. `Find what` : `^[a-z]+[0-9]`
2. `Replace with` : Do not enter anything
3. Make sure to select `Regular Expression` checkbox.
4. Hit `Replace All`